# Socket.io how to check a client's cookie data?

Tags: node.js, cookies, express, socket.io

I am building a to do list app, where several users can log onto the same list and view the items update in realtime - Google Docs style. I am using NodeJS, Express, Socket.io for the instant updates, and the `client-sessions` NodeJS module to store cookies to allow users to remain logged in.

I can load the correct items on the page with Express by rendering a Jade template, populating it with the items associated with the cookie on the requesting client, by creating a cookie under `req.session.user` with the user's details. However this only works when I have a `req` to get the session from, as in `app.get('/', function(req, res){});`.

However when I want to livestream the edits via socket.io, how can I make sure that the items edited are linked to the correct list? Is there any way of ascertaining what cookies the socket client has on the server?

I don't want to simply store a variable with the client's ID on the browser, because this will then be vulnerable, and won't take advantage of client-sessions's built in encryption.

Comment: Review http://socket.io/docs/server-api/  client.request will help you retrieve them.

Comment: @Gary amazing! Using `client.request.headers.cookie` does allow me to check the cookies. Now do you have any idea how I would decrypt it using the `client-sessions` secret?

Comment: If you look at the code for client-sessions (client-sessions.js), it exports the decode function.  I would start there.  It is not documented, so you probably will have to do some exploring...

Comment: session.decode({'cookieName':'name'}, cookie_content);

Comment: I am trying. This is what I've got so far: `session.util.decode({
  cookieName: "session",
  secret: "the_secret_string"
 }, client.request.headers.cookie`. However this just returns `undefined`. Any ideas?

Comment: The `encode` function does seem to work though, returning a random string of characters.

Comment: Ok I have just manually copied the encrypted cookie string named `session` to the `decode()` function and it did return the original cookie object! Why won't this work when I do this programmatically though?

Comment: Are you sure "session" is the name of the cookie?  Sounds like you are close.  Mark question answered if you can.

Comment: Yes, `session` is the name of the cookie. So after a lot of work I've gotten it to work - just. The cookie wasn't being parsed, and I don't know how to parse a cookie via `io` so I've got this convoluted function to give me the `session` cookie text: `client.request.headers.cookie.split("session=")[1]`. The decode function works on this and indeed returns the original object I stored in the cookie.

Comment: @Gary if you put your additional comments in the answer I will accept it.

Comment: Glad you got it working, I have updated the answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Review [socket.io/docs/server-api](http://socket.io/docs/server-api)

client.request will help you retrieve them.

If you look at the code for client-sessions (client-sessions.js), it exports the decode function. session.decode({'cookieName':'name'}, cookie_content);